# Package structure and jar file with manifest

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following "project" structure.

```
*Root/
     - manifest.txt
     + com/
          + mypackage/
                     + example/
                              - MyClass.java
                              - MyClass.class
```

I know from the docs.oracle.com documentation that the manifest file must be written in the UTF-8 character set and that there must be a space after each colon, and a carriage return ('\r') or a new line ('\n') before save file.

```
/* ** MANIFEST.TXT ** */

Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Class-Path: . 
Main-Class: com.mypackage.example.MyClass

/* ** END OF MANIFEST ** */
```

Creating an executable .jar file using cmd from the root directory.

**CMD:**

```
jar -cvfm out.jar manifest.txt com/mypackage/example/*.class
```

**OUTPUT from CMD:**

> **added manifest
> adding: com/mypackage/example/MyClass.class(in = 648) (out= 445)(deflated 31%)**

Now I'm trying to run the newly created jar file from the root directory:

```
java -jar out.jar
```

**OUTPUT from CMD:**

> **Error: Could not find or load main class com.mypackage.example.MyClass**

I can't get to the goal despite the last problem. What am I doing wrong??? Thank You.

Here is a screenshot of the screen and cmd.:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the screen and cmd]

Comment: Does `MyClass` have a `public static void main(String[] args)` entrypoint?

Comment: You'd get a different error if that was the problem, @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Yes. Of course. @Elliott Frisch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class-Path: com.mypackage.examples
Main-Class:My class

On Unix don't forget to set the .jar executable permission.

And alternate with no manifest.

Java -cp  thejar.jar com.mypackage.examples

Don't forget the main class must have a
public static void main(String args[])
method to start the class.

Comment: None of this is correct.  Packages are not “relative” like directories, so `Class-Path: com.mypackage.examples` will not work, and certainly does not allow a Main-Class line with no package.  Giving a .jar file executable permission has no effect whatsoever on its ability to be used by a `java -jar` command.  And the lack of a proper `main` would have caused a different error message.

Answer (score 2):

As you described it, you will get a running jar, and therefore, what you described is not an accurate representation of what you did.

A few steps to check:

1. Did you paste the *complete* error message? For example, maybe the error message includes the note `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyClass (wrong name: com/mypackage/MyClass)` or something along that vein. Then the problem is: Your `MyClass.java` needs to start with `package com.mypackage.example;`, it needs to contain `class MyClass` with that exact casing, and it needs to be called `MyClass.java` with that exact casing.
2. Did you actually do all the steps exactly as you laid out in your question? I did, and it works fine. This isn't one of those 'works on one machine and may not work on another' kind of scenarios, which is why I conclude you didn't. For example, if you include just `MyClass.class` and not `com/mypackage/example/MyClass.class` (i.e. you run the `jar` command from something that isn't the directory containing the `com` directory), you'd get this problem.

NB: 99% of folks building java jars use a build system to do so, such as maven or gradle.

Comment: No. I only get this problem in the package structure. Without a package, it works properly. I added a screenshot of my cmd to my question. I'm really only getting one mistake, which I mentioned here. @rzwitserloot

Comment: My class MyClass listed here on SO represents the class "Pokus" in the screenshot.